# Как получить id пользователя, и записать его в другую таблицу?

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть вот такое обращение к базе, которое добавляет нового пользователя:

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection (pathsql);
  MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand ("INSERT INTO Users(surname,firstname,gruppa) VALUES ('" + sname + "','" + fname + "','" + gr + "');");
  cmd.Connection = con;
  con.Open();
  MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  cmd.Connection.Close();
  con.Close();
```

как получить его id, и при этом записать в таблицу например `"INSERT INTO Users2(users_id) VALUES ('" + id + "')`
ничего не происходит при таких манипуляциях

как сделать это в первом коде вместе с добавлением пользователя?

Comment: id последней записи можно получить используя `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: ну и еще одно, каждый раз новые команды говорят, эта уже треться...ну ок, как это объединить???

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Users2 (users_id)
SELECT id
FROM Users
WHERE (surname,firstname,gruppa) 
   IN (@sname, @fname, @gr);
```